# Return value from one cell based off another

Tags: excel, lookup, formulas

In Excel I have a workbook with two active sheets. One sheet is used for raw data (labeled "Data") and the other is simply labeled "Sheet2". 'Data' contains the following information:

```
Column 1 = County
Column 2 = Street Address
Column 3 = City, State, Zip
Column 4 = Phone Number
```

In 'Sheet2' I have A1 as a drop down list that pulls off of the County column (Data!A:A). I currently have a formula in place in 'Sheet2' in the A2 - A4 cells. Here is an example of the formula I am currently using in Sheet2!A2 (with similar formulas for A3 and A4):

```
=IF(A1=Data!A2,Data!B2,IF(A1=Data!A3,Data!B3,IF(A1=Data!A4,Data!B4,
IF(A1=Data!A5,Data!B5,IF(A1=Data!A6,Data!B6,
IF(A1=Data!A7,Data!B7,IF(A1=Data!A8,Data!B8,
IF(A1=Data!A9,Data!B9,IF(A1=Data!A10,Data!B10,
IF(A1=Data!A11,Data!B11,IF(A1=Data!A12,Data!B12,
IF(A1=Data!A13,Data!B13,IF(A1=Data!A14,Data!B14,
IF(A1=Data!A15,Data!B15,IF(A1=Data!A16,Data!B16,
IF(A1=Data!A17,Data!B17,IF(A1=Data!A18,Data!B18,
IF(A1=Data!A19,Data!B19,IF(A1=Data!A20,Data!B20,
IF(A1=Data!A21,Data!B21,IF(A1=Data!A22,Data!B22,
IF(A1=Data!A23,Data!B23,IF(A1=Data!A24,Data!B24,
IF(A1=Data!A25,Data!B25))))))))))))))))))))))))
```

But the above formula requires me to input another IF formula every time I add a new county. This list continues to grow thus requiring me to frequently update the formula.

I am sure there is an easier way to accomplish what I am attempting to do without the hassle.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,Data!A2:B25,2)
```

This allows us to avoid a vast array of nested `IF`s.